# My site does not work if I put a www in front

Tags: domain-name-system

I have just moved my site from one host to another. Now, when I type the site url without the www prefix ( ie http://example.com ), the site does show up ( though without the stylesheets, but that may be another problem ), but when I type it with the prefix (http://www.example.com) the site does not show up at all and returns a 404 error. I did add an A record in the DNS for www.example.com, that pointed to the same server as the original , but it still does not work.

Can you please help out and let me know what could be the problem.

Comment: Is this on a shared hosting account?

Comment: check with your hosting company or your webserver if it is "your" host.
you maybe did not setup your vhost settings for the webserver.

Answer (score 1):

If you made the change only a little bit ago, wait and try again after 1 hour.  Depending on your NS provider, it could take a while to populate across the internets.  You can also `nslookup - xx.xx.xx.xx` where `xx.xx.xx.xx` is your NS, then type `www.example.com` and hit enter to see if your A record was generated properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have verified that your DNS records are fine, then you might need to talk to your host. A www subdomain is not always created by default on the webserver why they would have to create this for you.